# How to properly use Factory_girl and has_many 'through' models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm having a little difficulty groking the call back model and methodology in Factory Girl.  Using this post http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/254496652/aint-no-calla-back-girl I started giving it a go and, now I'm erroring in the spec.  I am new to Rails...so I may be missing something really fundamental.

The Error is:
Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:admin_user)
undefined method 'each' for #

The Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :lockable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatble

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :role_ids, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :userroles
  has_many :roles, :through=>:userroles


  def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
  end
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, :presence=>true,
                   :length=>{:minimum=>4, :maximum=>30}

  has_many :userroles
  has_many :users, :through=>:userroles
end

class Userrole < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :role_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

The Factories:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.email 'someone@somecompany.com'
  f.username 'foo'
  f.password '123456'
end

Factory.define :role do |r|
  r.name 'testrole'
end

Factory.define :userrole do |ur|
  ur.association(:role)
  ur.userrole{|ur| ur.userrole(:user)}
end
Factory.define :admin_role, :class => 'Role' do |userrole|
  userrole.role { |role| role.association(:role, :name => "Admin") }
end

Factory.define :admin_user, :parent => :user do |user|
  user.after_create { |u| Factory(:admin_role, :userroles => u) }
end
```

Lastly the simple spec:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe RolesController do
  fixtures :all
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  render_views

before (:each) do
    @user = Factory(:admin_user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  it "index action should render index template" do
    get :index
    response.should render_template(:index)
  end
end
```

Update: Adding Stack Trace

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > u=Factory(:admin_user)
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<User:0x00000004d737d8>
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:352:in `replace'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1524:in `block in collection_accessor_methods'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/proxy/build.rb:13:in `set'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:320:in `block in run'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:320:in `each'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:320:in `run'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:270:in `create'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:301:in `default_strategy'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl.rb:20:in `Factory'
    from /home/ryan/Sites/Holocron/spec/factories/users.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/proxy.rb:29:in `call'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/proxy.rb:29:in `block in run_callbacks'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/proxy.rb:28:in `each'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/proxy.rb:28:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/proxy/create.rb:7:in `result'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:327:in `run'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:270:in `create'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:301:in `default_strategy'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/factory_girl-1.3.2/lib/factory_girl.rb:20:in `Factory'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@Holocron/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I am just now getting into RoR but shouldn't <code>it "index action should render index template" do</code> be <code>if "index action should render index template" do</code> in the last spec?

Comment: @jostster - "it" is a concept of rspec... basically it's says "this is what it should do" now do it. The part in quotes gets output on the console so that you can read the results in a more human fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you've confused yourself.

You've defined `Factory.define :admin_role, :class => 'Role' do |userrole|` as a `Role` but then in your factory definition you treat it like a `Userrole`. (BTW, Ruby conventions use underlines – so Userrole would be UserRole/user_role.)

Also, your `user.after_create { |u| Factory(:admin_role, :userroles => u) }` probably ought to be: `user.after_create { |u| Factory(:admin_role, :userroles => [u]) }` since a `Role` `has_many :userroles`.